# can't get signed url for images soterd in gc storage incloud run nodejs server

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1QFw.png)

the server was working fine localy because json key but on the gc run unexpectedly gave me this error

i tried to add "Service Account Token Creator"  role
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2B7y.png)
but still no work
added this role to more places but no luck !

Comment: The service account attached to the Cloud Run service does not have permission to sign data. The screenshot shows "Service Account Token Creator", but the service account that you are actually using does not have that permission. Run this command `gcloud run services describe CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME`. Find `Service account` in the output. Then check which roles are assigned to that service account.

Comment: As a last resort after verifying the correct IAM role, redeploy the Cloud Run service.

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you, I found the real imposter Service Acc.  now what role should assign that acc. ? "Service Account Token Creator" right ?

Comment: Yes, that role has the required permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem, the Cloud Run service is not using the service account that you think it is.

Execute the following CLI command:

`gcloud run services describe <CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE_NAME>`

Find the entry for `Service account` in the output. That is the service account assigned to the service.

To sign data, the service account must have the permission `iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob`. The recommended IAM role is `Service Account Token Creator`.

To add that role execute the following command:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-binding <PROJECT_ID> \
--member=serviceAccount:<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS> \
--role=roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```

To list the service account's Project IAM bindings:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy <PROJECT_ID> \
--flatten="bindings[].members" \
--format="table(bindings.role)" \
--filter="bindings.members:<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS>"
```

If you want tighter security, you can assign the IAM role to the service account itself so that the service account can only sign data using its own service account and not using another service account:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding <SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS> \
--member=<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL_ADDRESS> \
--role=roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```

Notice that this command assigns the permission to itself. The service account email address is specified twice. The first time as the resource. The second time as a member.